# Catch all Powershell errors using Try/Catch/Finally

Tags: powershell

I have a 1500+ lines Powershell script that has been enhanced to log progress and errors to Azure Table Storage.

The problem is that not all errors are logged.

Is this the easiest way to accomplish this without changing the script too much and catching all errors?

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

function a
{
    "a"
}

function b
{
    "b"
    Get-Content foo
}

function c
{
    "c"
}

Try
{
    a
    b
    c
}
Catch
{
    "Catch & Log Error"
    $Error[0].Exception
}
Finally
{
    "The End"
}
```

**UPDATE**

The output is:

```
a
b
Catch & Log Error
Cannot find path 'C:\foo' because it does not exist.
The End
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish or what don't you understand about this code? What are you expecting this code to do vs what it actually does? works as expected to me

Comment: Just to be clear, doing it that way means if you have an error in a, then b and c will never execute.

Comment: Check out [Trap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347548.aspx)

Comment: There is a difference between terminating and non-terminating errors. You can catch terminating errors but not non-terminating errors.  By setting ErrorActionPrefrence to Stop, that will convert non-terminating errors into terminating errors.  You will be able to "catch" all errors but as @EBGreen points out, your script will now halt on any error.  The same applies to the Trap statement.  If that's what you want, you're good to go.

Comment: Another option if you don't necessarily want to stop on non-terminating errors is to clear the $error collection at the start of your script and examine its contents at the end.  It will contain all errors.

Comment: Or if you want to keep the past errors in the $error collection, just check the count on the collection at the beginning and end and look at the ones that occured during the run.

Comment: Apologies if the question was unclear. The script is an application installation script which contains ~75 functions with rather complex logic. I do not want to make too much changes to the existing logic. I need to stop the script at *any* error(s) and log the error(s) to Azure Table Storage. So I was hoping that setting $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" and using a Try around the "Main block" does the job without too much changes to the existing logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can place this at the top of your script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Stop
```

... all errors will then 'act' like terminating errors & be caught by a `try...catch` block.